# How can I change the Chrome Dock Tile Icon to show the favicon of the current tab?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dock

I would like my Chrome Dock Tile to show the (dynamic) favicon of a tab.  There are several scenarios I could imagine, any of which would be incredibly useful to me:

- The Chrome Dock Tile icon is completely replaced by the favicon.
- The Chrome Dock Tile shows the favicon in, for instance, the lower right hand corner of the main icon, similar to the download indicator.
- The favicon is that of the front-most Chrome tab.
- The favicon is that of a specific, pinned tab.

A solution that was live would be ideal, but an AppleScript I could set to run every 5 minutes or something would also be ok.

My use case is that I have Gmail set to display the number of unread messages in my Inbox in the favicon.  I would like to have that displayed in the Dock so I could see if I have new unread messages without bringing Chrome to the front.

Comment: If the App itself does not provide this function, you'll need to write an app that can do what you've asked.  Some sample Dock Tile code can be found with the [DockTile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/DockTile/Introduction/Intro.html) app from Apple demos simple use of the NSDockTile API and more. Keep in mind that the the favicon.ico file typically has one 16x16 image that would then need to be scaled larger and saved to the .icns format to be placed in the Dock. This will probably look ugly compared to proper creation which uses a larger master image and scales that down.

Comment: If you want to change it like this, I would recommend modifying Google's Chromium (https://www.chromium.org/), this is basically the open source version of Chrome.

Comment: If I had to write my own code anyway, I would probably skip Chrome altogether and just write an app that polled for new messages via IMAP and set its own icon accordingly. Hmm...  Thanks for the tips, especially the pointer to the demo app.